# Angular CLI application does not work with I.E. in production

Tags: angular-cli, angular5

I created an application using Angular-CLI 1.6.5 (Angular 5.2.1), and modified the polyfills.ts file such that all 'polyfills' are un-commented. As a result, the application works fine using Chrome or I.E. in my development environment.

However, when I create a production version of my application ( using : ng build -e=prod --prod --no-sourcemap --aot ), and transferring the content of the 'dist' folder to my production server, the application again only works in Chrome but not in I.E., just like it would in the development environment without changing the polyfills.ts file in the Angular CLI environment.

Does anybody know the trick to make an Angular 5 project work in production in combination with I.E. ?

Comment: post your environment files.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the cause of the issues it. As I stated before, I already updated my poyfills.ts file, but that did not help.
What did solve the issue was to change the I.E. settings to NOT show the page(s) in compatibility view. Change the settings, and it works just fine ....